# using a variable in a filename in python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I think i've conquered 95% of this short script to make images out of individual pixels, but I'd like help with using a variable as part of a filename. the line in question is as follows (i've used {} to denote the place I want to insert the variable):

```
 img.save("new\\{i, j}.png")
```

The full code is

```
# Importing Image from PIL package
from PIL import Image
 
# Creating image object
im = Image.open("C:\\Users\\joeco\\Desktop\\Python-test-image\\image.jpg")
px = im.load()

# Defining image width and height
imageSizeW, imageSizeH = im.size

# Running through each pixel coord by column then row
for i in range(1, imageSizeW):
    for j in range(1, imageSizeH):

# Removing non white pixels, then saving a single pixel of the colour to a new file        
        if px != (255, 255, 255):
         img = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), color = (px[i, j]))
         img.save("new\\{i, j}.png")
```

Comment: Please give some examples of actual filenames you are expecting your program to create.

Comment: I think you're looking for `img.save(f"new\\{i}, {j}.png")`

Comment: It should give the coordinates as the filename so 1,1.png then 1,2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the character `f` before a string if you want to include variables in that manner. In your example, you would use `img.save(f"new\\{i}, {j}.png")`

You could also use `%i` to save the filename like so: `img.save("new\\%i, %i.png" % (i, j))`

Comment: As also commented above by Paul m, the f is the key! Thank you for writing out the correct answer.
"You have to use the character f before a string if you want to include variables in that manner. In your example, you would use img.save(f"new\\{i}, {j}.png")"